# Have git push assume -u origin $branch

Tags: git, git-branch

When I create a local branch with Git, I would prefer to be able to assume that a push will track origin with the same name.

Right now, the following:

```
git checkout -b $branch
git push
```

Yields

```
fatal: The current branch $branch has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin $branch
```

Can I add something to .gitconfig to allow me to push *without* needing to `git push -u origin $branch`?

Comment: Just create an alias "got config --global alias.p "push -u origin HEAD".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. At least, it does not do what I expected. Setting this config and then running `git push` will not push the current (new) branch. The output is "everything is up to date", which is misleading if you had the same expectation as I did. I still have to run `git push -u origin [branch-name]` the very first time I'm pushing a branch to the remote.

Comment: Hey Josh - I'm trying `current` instead of `matching`. It does push the current (new) branch. Hopefully it doesn't cause any unwanted side effects...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set the upstream once per branch by using `git push --set-upstream origin $URL`, then you should always be able to do a simple `git push`.

You can see the reason why they made this decision by checking out the [release notes for git v1.8 rc1](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/ANNOUNCE-Git-v1-8-0-rc1-tc7568792.html).

Comment: OK. I understand the reason why they would want to do that, but I don't want to have to do that every time I make a branch. I'm looking for a way to set a preference to automatically accomplish -u without specifying.